# Get running threads information in an Application

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm developing desktop application,
where I upload series of FPGA files on scanning device, to do this job I have **COM DLL** provided by driver.

For uploading files I call method named "StartWrite", which start worker thread to write FPGA to device.

And now in C# how do I get list/information (expected execution time etc.) of worker threads in application ?

Answer (score 1):

How do you suppose any sort of code would be able to tell what is the "expected execution time" of a thread?

I think the best pattern would be if your `StartWrite` method returned an [`IAsyncResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.aspx). With that, you would be able to check if the writing has ended.

Threading is not a simple subject, though. Here is a good source of information about [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).